# Why repeatable read is found after update when using EclispseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

With default database isolation level (read-committed), it is expected that non-repeatable read can happen from a transaction when there is another transaction has write commit. However, when I tried to test this behavior. Repeatable read result is found. Below is the step I used:

1. begin transaction T1
2. select the row T1 (OldValue is retrieved)
3. Breakpoint
4. modify the row with NewValue T2
5. select the row again T1 (OldValue is retrieved)

Beside, I tried to disable JPA/EclipseLink cache, but got the same result.

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
...
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: When I tried with entityManager.clear() after the first select, it is able to produce non-repeatable read. Why it is still cached?

Comment: I'm afraid, you are mixing the names. *Repeatable read* is another [transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html), but not a *phenomenon*, so it cannot be *observed*. -- The documentation states multiple times that *the four isolation levels only define which phenomena must not happen, not which phenomena **must** happen.* If you think it *can* happen, but you can't observe it, that is probably the right behavior too.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, revised description

Comment: How did you change the value in step 4? Maybe you didn't commit the update? Also: does this also happen if you leave out the obfuscation layer and do it manually? What does `show default_transaction_isolation` give you? Maybe your Postgres server was configured to use a different isolation level.

Comment: The value is committed. If I use entityManager.clear() after the first select in step 2, the second select in step 5 will show NewValue.

Comment: Then this is clearly a (caching) problem with your obfuscation layer (=JPA), not with Postgres

Comment: Revised question

Comment: Please remember that there are 2 levels of caching within JPA; the shared cache and then the EntityManager cache.  The EntityManager cache maintains the managed entities, so that changes to them can be synchronized to the database when the transaction commits. You can try to force a refresh with entityManager.refresh and see if your values are loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Chris I can get the NewValue with refresh now